# Unbrick Unlocked Huawei P10 - SOLVED

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, unbricking, huawei, emui

I messed around with my phone (Huawei P10 VTR-L29) and unfortunately bricked it.

### what happened

To give you the whole story, I tried to root it, but during the root process I found out that the device is encrypted so I had to "rollback". That worked fine and my phone was working ok with one issue - I wasn't able to update firmware via regular system updates. I saw the update, but wasn't able to download and install - it always ended up with some error.

That made me decide to reinstall the firmware from scratch. I followed general steps but yeah, I messed up.

### current status

The only thing I can see now is

[image: Emui Recovery]

When I click on download latest version and recovery

[image: Downloading]

But after a while it fails:

[image: Failure]

And I am stuck :( I can't get any further .. I tried to connect via ADB (but since I cannot get in the phone to enable USB Debugging (which might be the problem) I am unable to connect (nor ADB neither FASTBOOT can see the device).

I tried to create this file:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

But when I run

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
adb devices
```

It's still empty ... I can't even get to the "FACTORY RESET" by pressing and holding POWER + VOL:DOWN for some time; it always brings me back to the Huawei eRecovery

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this? 
Or is that phone dead for good?

I don't care about the data inside.. I would only love to make it work again

## EDIT

with the help of alecxs I made it to the fastboot&rescue mode

[image: Fastboot and recovery mode]

however this

```
sudo fastboot boot [img]
```

ends up with

```
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  1.052s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 1.056s
```

similar for

```
sudo fastboot flash recovery [img]
```

ends up with

```
target reported max download size of 471859200 bytes
sending 'recovery' (32040 KB)...
OKAY [  0.995s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 1.001s
```

### EDIT2:

I asked as well one of my friends and we moved on a bit more ...

I tried to unlock the bootloader

```
sudo fastboot oem unlock [unlock_code]
```

Then I got this screen:

[image: bootloader_Unlock]

I went with the option (2) and that brought me to the first screen mentioned in this article "Huawei eRecovery"

but when I repeated  the VOL:DOWN + USB:CABLE:PLUG trick :) I got this

[image: Unlocked_phone]

I tried a different TWRP (for P10 specifically) from this link: [XDA Devs - P10 TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/p10/development/recovery-twrp-3-2-1-0-emui-8-0-4-04-2018-t3773449)

Flashing worked fine:

```
sudo fastboot flash recovery_ramdisk twrp_p10_0.1.img
```

I got:

```
target reported max download size of 471859200 bytes
sending 'recovery_ramdisk' (24954 KB)...
OKAY [  0.771s]
writing 'recovery_ramdisk'...
OKAY [  0.232s]
finished. total time: 1.003s
```

after

```
sudo fastboot reboot
```

right after this command, I need to unplug the USB cable and hold VOLUME:UP to be able to get to TWRP (swipe.d to allow modifications) ... am there already

[image: TWRP]

now I am looking for any ROM for my P10 to flash it. I want to try this one: [TheUpgradeGuide.com - Pixel Experience](http://theupgradeguide.com/2019/12/20/install-android-9-0-pie-on-huawei-p10-p10-plus-pixel-experience-rom-how-to-guide/)

I downloaded the gApps and ROM ... uploaded it to the "Internal Storage" of the phone (there was a folder TWRP so I put it next to it)

```
.
..
/TWRP
rom.7z
gapps.zip
```

Went on wiping -> WIPE -> ADVANCED -> checked these

- Dalvik Cache
- System
- Cache
- Data

swiped to wipe (uplugged USB) .. but got this error:

```
Updating partition details ...
Failed to mount '/odm' (Invalid argument)
...done
Failed to unmount '/system' (Device or resource busy)
Full SELinux support is present
MTP Enabled
Failed to unmount '/system' (Device or resource busy)
Wiping Dalvik Cache Directories...
--Dalvik Cache Directories Wipe Complete!
Formatting Cache using make-ext4fs...
Wiping data without wiping /data/media ...
Done.
Failed to unmount '/system' (Device or resource busy)
Unable to wipe /system.
Updating partition details...
Failed to mount '/odm' (Invalid argument)
...done
```

### EDIT 3

in the  `adb shell`

```
~ # mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,seclabel,size=1457112k,nr_inodes=364278)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime,gid=3009,hidepid=2)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
none on /acct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct)
tmpfs on /mnt type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
none on /config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/secure_storage on /sec_storage type ext4 (rw,context=u:object_r:teecd_data_file:s0,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered)
adb on /dev/usb-ffs/adb type functionfs (rw,relatime)
hdb on /dev/usb-ffs/hdb type functionfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system on /system type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/vendor on /vendor type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /storage type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
/dev/block/sdd46 on /data type f2fs (rw,seclabel,relatime,background_gc=on,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,verify_encrypt,active_logs=6)
/dev/block/sdd46 on /sdcard type f2fs (rw,seclabel,relatime,background_gc=on,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,verify_encrypt,active_logs=6)
/dev/block/sdd13 on /cache type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
```

plus the ls output

```
~ # ls -ld $(find /dev/block -name by-name)/*
drwxr-xr-x    2 root         root              1020 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/boot_a -> /dev/block/sdd32
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/bootfail_info -> /dev/block/sdd14
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/cache -> /dev/block/sdd13
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/cust_a -> /dev/block/sdd43
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/dfx -> /dev/block/sdd19
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/dts_a -> /dev/block/sdd34
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/fastboot_a -> /dev/block/sdd24
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/frp -> /dev/block/sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/fw_hifi_a -> /dev/block/sdd28
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/fw_lpm3_a -> /dev/block/sdd21
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/hisee_fs -> /dev/block/sdd18
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/hisee_img_a -> /dev/block/sdd23
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/isp_boot_a -> /dev/block/sdd26
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/isp_firmware_a -> /dev/block/sdd27
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/misc -> /dev/block/sdd15
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/modem_fw_a -> /dev/block/sdd36
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/modem_om -> /dev/block/sdd7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/modem_secure -> /dev/block/sdd3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/modemnvm_backup -> /dev/block/sdd9
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/modemnvm_factory -> /dev/block/sdd8
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/modemnvm_img -> /dev/block/sdd10
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/modemnvm_system -> /dev/block/sdd11
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/modemnvm_update_a -> /dev/block/sdd38
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/nvme -> /dev/block/sdd4
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/oeminfo -> /dev/block/sdd5
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/patch_a -> /dev/block/sdd39
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/persist -> /dev/block/sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/product_a -> /dev/block/sdd42
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/recovery2_a -> /dev/block/sdd30
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/recovery_a -> /dev/block/sdd33
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/reserved1 -> /dev/block/sdc3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/reserved10 -> /dev/block/sdd17
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/reserved2 -> /dev/block/sdd16
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/reserved3_a -> /dev/block/sdd22
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/reserved4_a -> /dev/block/sdd37
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/reserved5 -> /dev/block/sdd45
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/rrecord -> /dev/block/sdd20
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/secure_storage -> /dev/block/sdd6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/sensorhub_a -> /dev/block/sdd31
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/splash2 -> /dev/block/sdd12
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/system_a -> /dev/block/sdd44
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/teeos_a -> /dev/block/sdd29
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/trustfirmware_a -> /dev/block/sdd35
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/userdata -> /dev/block/sdd46
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/vector_a -> /dev/block/sdd25
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/vendor_a -> /dev/block/sdd41
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                16 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/version_a -> /dev/block/sdd40
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/vrl -> /dev/block/sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                15 Jan  4 18:02 /dev/block/platform/ff3b0000.ufs/by-name/vrl_backup -> /dev/block/sdd2
```

Ok, with the help of alecxs I managed to get a bit further (see the chat) but it seems like the TWRP is faulty (the one from the link above -> XDA).. nonetheless, any other TWRP is not working at all and I am landing on this screen instead :(

[image: Invalid TWRP]

### EDIT 4:

output of `fastboot getvar all` is here:

```
getvar:all FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
```

### EDIT 5:

see the output of the fastboot commands requested in the chat

```
#sudo fastboot oem get-bootinfo
...
(bootloader)  unlocked
OKAY [  0.006s]
finished. total time: 0.006s

$ sudo fastboot getvar vendorcountry
vendorcountry: hw/eu
finished. total time: 0.007s

$ sudo fastboot oem get-build-number
...
(bootloader) :VTR-L29C432B151
OKAY [  0.007s]
finished. total time: 0.007s

$ sudo fastboot oem oeminforead-SYSTEM_VERSION
...
(bootloader) :VTR-L29C432B151
OKAY [  0.008s]
finished. total time: 0.008s
```

## SOLVED

Finally, I made it and the phone is up and running :)

I downloaded Huru Updated (v0.3)
and these files
https://huaweidl.com/download/huawei-p10/vtr-l29/b151/

Followed these steps:
https://www.getdroidtips.com/hurupdater-tool/

and yaaaay, it works :) after months of playing around ... big thx to alecxs for his immense help !!! this guys is a genius !!!

the only question now is to get from Android 7 (the stock I flashed) to 9.1 (the most updated one provided to p10) ... bec the native system update does not offer me an update :D but that's minor ..

EDIT:
ok, following this manual [xda-developers - Jannomag](https://forum.xda-developers.com/p10/how-to/guide-manual-updgrade-to-update-oreo-t3758286) I was able to upgrade to 8.0 (with a little hiccup - just had to manually restart it multiple times) and then to 9.0 (no problem at all this time) and right after 9.0 it offered me (via system update) automatically the newest 9.1.0.263

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109992/discussion-between-mr-p-and-alecxs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLUTION

Here is what I have done to make it work ...

I downloaded HuRu Updater (v0.3) and these files https://huaweidl.com/download/huawei-p10/vtr-l29/b151/

Followed these steps: https://www.getdroidtips.com/hurupdater-tool/

and yaaaay, it works :) after months of playing around ... big thx to alecxs for his immense help !!! this guy is a genius !!!

the only question was to get from Android 7 / EMUI 5.1 (the stock I flashed) to 9.1 (the most updated one provided to p10) ... bec the native system update did not offer me an update

but by following this manual [xda-developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/p10/how-to/guide-manual-updgrade-to-update-oreo-t3758286) - Jannomag I was able to upgrade to 8.0 (with a little hiccup - just had to manually restart it multiple times because the phone was not rebooting as expected and somehow got "stock") and then to 9.0 (no problem at all this time; smooth) and right after 9.0 it offered me (via system update) automatically the newest 9.1.0.263

The only thing left is that I have an unlocked bootloader and cannot seem to be able to lock it again with

```
fastboot oem lock [unlock_code]
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)

fastboot oem relock [unlock_code]
FAILED (remote: root type is risk)
```

but that's minor ... I will try to look for a way to do that .. and if successful, I will update this answer with the final steps to get back to "stock"

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3769279

Comment: yes - that one :) thx

Comment: i recommend to keep bootloader unlocked for emergency purposes, this way you can still boot twrp from fastboot

Comment: that's right...it's just the annoying screen while booting hehe ... as I said, it's a minor and I won't probably bother with that...